# Is it possible to justify text within the bootstrap framework?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This might be a silly question but I'm certain I'm not the only one wondering.

I'm aware of the alignment classes:
`<p class="text-center">Text Centered within the block element</p>`
`<p class="text-right">Text aligned to the right within the block element</p>`
`<p class="text-left">Text aligned to the left within the block element</p>`

Is there a set of classes in Twitters Bootstrap Framework that justifies text?

e.g. `<p class="text-justify">Sample Text Goes Here</p>`

why does it appear that bootstrap do not incorporate a utility function such as `text-align: justify`?

Comment: Why not just define your own css class with `text-align: justify`?

Comment: Probably because justified text is rarely used on the web (and print media is moving further and further away from traditional full justification every year).  It's childs play to make your own `.text-justify` class though.

Comment: I wondered more why it wasn't incorporated into the bootstrap release.

I totally agree that making the class is easy - So to humble me it begs the question why haven't they incorporated it in to the framework.

And is that based on your own experience that text isn't justified Ennui? I go on a lot of sites where the text appears to be justified and or at least laid out in such a way that it appears that way. can you link to any reference about media moving away from justified text.. It helps satisfy the client's curiosity is all

Comment: Entrenched in our experiences,   see that Word starts left aligned, not justified.  We write aligned, not justified.  Even sublime text, textmate, or the adobe suite aren't justified to start.

Comment: @chrisFrisina, note worthy points and indeed something I'll remember, thank you. Don't think me rude but I do not find default settings a persuasive argument against the incorporation of a justified text classes on bootstrap though.

Comment: Not at all either, merely an explanation of why.   Most dev's copy previous functionality until something/someone requires us to take a look at why.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

No. But you can add a new class on **bootstrap.css**

```
.text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

**Update**

Previous versions of bootstrap was not supporting `text-justify`. 
But bootstrap 3 has added a class `text-justify`.

Answer (score 88):

In **Bootstrap 3** and **Bootstrap 4** you can use the following:

```
<p class="text-justify">Justified text.</p>
```

[Official documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/text/)

(Update) This feature removed from **Bootstrap 5**

- [Commit](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/29793)
- [Official document and recommendation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

> Note that we don't provide utility classes for justified text. While, aesthetically, justified text might look more appealing, it does make word-spacing more random and therefore harder to read.

Based on the official UX suggestion: don't use justified text! ;)

Comment: @EdisonPebojot Thanks for the heads up. Yep, it looks, this is removed from version 5 and this feature does not exist there anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can add to your **`main.css`**, **`custom.css`**, or whichever **`*.css`** file you have made, or to the top of **`bootstrap.css`** file directly:

```
.text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

If you add this to the **`bootstrap.css`** file direcetly, as of v3.0.0, it would go from this:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.0.0
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world by @mdo and @fat.
 */

/*! normalize.css v2.1.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

article,
aside,
details,
...
...
…
```

to

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.0.0
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Twitter, Inc
 * Licensed under the Apache License v2.0
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Designed and built with all the love in the world by @mdo and @fat.
 */

/*! normalize.css v2.1.0 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */

.text-justify {
  text-align: justify;
}

article,
aside,
details,
...
...
…
```

Comment: I would leave the main.css alone in favour of using the minified files and add a custom .css file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class available for this in Bootstrap.

```
class = 'text-justify'
```

You can check out the text-alignment in [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/).

Answer (score 0):

In **Bootstrap 5** there is no built-in class for this, but we can use **[Bootstrap Utility API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/)** to extend the existing `text-align` utilities and generate `text-justify` class.

By default, Bootstrap 5 generates the following classes for text alignment: `text-start`, `text-center`, `text-end` (and their responsive versions).

We can generate the `text-justify` class by adding an additional value to the `text-align` utilities:

```scss
$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "text-align": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "text-align"),
      (
        values: map-merge(
          map-get(map-get($utilities, "text-align"), "values"),
          (justify: justify),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

Full SCSS code:

```scss
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities";

// extend `text-align` utility
$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    "text-align": map-merge(
      map-get($utilities, "text-align"),
      (
        values: map-merge(
          map-get(map-get($utilities, "text-align"), "values"),
          (justify: justify),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
);

// include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
@import "bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

**DEMO**:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-5-qjdfsx?file=src%2Fstyles.scss

CSS Output:

```css
.text-justify { text-align: justify !important; }

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .text-sm-justify { text-align: justify !important; }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .text-md-justify { text-align: justify !important; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .text-lg-justify { text-align: justify !important; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .text-xl-justify { text-align: justify !important; }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  .text-xxl-justify { text-align: justify !important; }
}
```